# MetaData in header of GeoJSON

Tags: geojson

Would it break most readers (and violate the spec) if I added some meta-data at the top of a GeoJSON file (or packet).

I looked at: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/96158/metadata-and-geojson

But I am not clear if that answered my question here.

For example, can an add more properties to the CRS object, other than "name", "properties" to get some extended meta-data, rather than putting it on each feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The geojson specs section 6.1 state (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946):

> 6.1.  Foreign Members
>
> Members not described in this specification ("foreign members") MAY be
> used in a GeoJSON document.  Note that support for foreign members can
> vary across implementations, and no normative processing model for
> foreign members is defined.  Accordingly, implementations that rely
> too heavily on the use of foreign members might experience reduced
> interoperability with other implementations.
>
> For example, in the (abridged) Feature object shown below
>
> {
> "type": "Feature",
> "id": "f1",
> "geometry": {...},
> "properties": {...},
> "title": "Example Feature"    }
>
> the name/value pair of "title": "Example Feature" is a foreign member.
> When the value of a foreign member is an object, all the descendant
> members of that object are themselves foreign members.
> GeoJSON semantics do not apply to foreign members and their descendants, regardless of their names and values.  For example, in
> the (abridged) Feature object below
>
> {
> "type": "Feature",
> "id": "f2",
> "geometry": {...},
> "properties": {...},
> "centerline": {
> "type": "LineString",
> "coordinates": [
> [-170, 10],
> [170, 11]
> ]
> }    }
>
> the "centerline" member is not a GeoJSON Geometry object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about whether it violates specs, but I did something similar and it did not break the reader.

For example, I had a GeoJSON file with 10 features, and wanted to add a time stamp to it. I accomplished this with Javascript (Node.js):

```
var json_in = require('/path/to/file/input.json');
var timei = ("2016-10-31 12Z");
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
var file = '/path/to/file/output.json';

jsonfile.writeFile(file, json_in, function (err) {
console.error(err)
})
```

I then mapped out the features on http://geojson.io and confirmed that everything looked right.

FYI You can get the jsonfile package (makes I/O much smoother) here:
https://github.com/jprichardson/node-jsonfile